# How does a CPU timer work if the count value is larger than what it can hold?

Tags: c, linux, timer, cpu-architecture

If I'm not mistaking, the C `sleep` function is one of the places a CPU timer is used.
Linux will set a timer and removes the process from the `scheduler`. Timer counts `down` and once it hits `0` it will interrupt the CPU and the OS will re-add the process to the scheduler. Am I correct about this?

If so  then what happens if the timer value is larger than the number of bits the counter hardware can handle? Let's say the counter has a max of `23` bits and I need a `24` bit value (i.e I need to `sleep` for a long time).

Edit:

Also, what If we have multiple  sleeps going on at the same time, more than the CPU has counters for?

Comment: A modern PC has many hardware timers with advanced capabilities, so this case is unlikely to occur.  But in principle, the easiest solution would be for the OS to keep another counter in software, tracking how many times the hardware counter needs to roll over before the process should be resumed.  Every time the hardware counter hits 0, an interrupt is generated, and the interrupt handler decrements the software counter, and only if the software counter has reached 0 does anything further happen.

Comment: I see, my other question was, what If we have multiple  `sleep`s going on at the same time, more than the CPU has counters for? I guess the software will be used in that case?

Comment: Just like you do in real life: your wall clock wraps around every 24 hours, but every time it does so, you mark off a page in your calendar.  So you can track arbitrary lengths of time even though your only hardware timekeeping device can't do so by itself.

Comment: Sure, have a counter for every sleeping process, and when an interrupt fires, decrement all of them, then see which ones have hit 0.  This is an very simplified description; the actual kernel uses more sophisticated and efficient algorithms.

Comment: but in the case of having multiples `sleeps`, how woulds software know which interrupt is for which sleep?

Comment: There's only one interrupt.  The kernel works out which process needs to wake up first, calculates how long until that should happen, and sets the hardware timer to fire after that length of time.  When it does, it adjusts the remaining time needed for each process (a value kept in software), wakes up any that are ready to wake up, calculates how long until the next one needs to wake up, and continues.

Answer (score 1):

> sleep function is one of the places a CPU timer is used

No.  The Linux kernel implements a [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)).  When you call [`nanosleep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) (the GNU C library on Linux uses `nanosleep()` to implement `sleep()`), you do a nanosleep [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call); this causes the kernel to not schedule that task (usually a thread in a userspace process) before the desired duration has elapsed, or a signal is delivered to an userspace signal handler installed without the SA_RESTART flag using that task (in which case the system call returns with `-EINTR`).

On a microcontroller, say an Arduino or similar, you *can* implement sleeping using a timer, though.

Let's say you have a timer facility that can count from anywhere up to `TIMER_MAX` to zero, i.e. sleep for any number of time units between 1 and `TIMER_MAX`. If you want to sleep for a longer duration, you can do so in `TIMER_MAX` intervals:

```
/* Timer-based sleep function; returns the number of units slept,
   at most 'units'.  Can only sleep between 1 and TIMER_MAX, inclusive. */
static unsigned short  timer_sleep(unsigned short units);

void sleep(unsigned long duration)
{
    /* "long" sleep(s) */
    while (duration >= TIMER_MAX)
        duration -= timer_sleep(TIMER_MAX);

    /* "short" sleep(s) */
    while (duration > 0)
        duration -= timer_sleep(duration);
}
```

You could replace the latter while loop with just a `timer_sleep(duration)`, if `timer_sleep(u)` always returns `u`.  Written as above, using two while loops, the sleep will work as long as `timer_sleep(u)` returns `u` or less.

Comment: But how will the kernel get notified when the time is up and it has to re-add the program to the scheduler? a timer isn't doing that?

Comment: @Dan: The kernel uses lists or trees to maintain the tasks. It lets each task run for a bit, then examines its lists/trees which task to let run for the next bit.  (This part, letting the task run for only a bit, does use a timer interrupt: this way even if the userspace is in a tight loop, control goes back to the kernel when the time slice is up. In Linux, this is typically between 0.01s and 0.001s, so very very short intervals; with dynticks, it varies all the time).  Part of this examination is to see if there are tasks that need to be woken up, because they have slept long enough.

Comment: How would it run multiple programs as you explained given only few number of timer hardwares in CPU?

Comment: @Dan: Only one hardware timer is needed, and it is used by the kernel itself to generate a hardware interrupt (returning execution back to the kernel) when the next time slice is over.  Software timers, like those created via POSIX [timer_create()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), are just kernel data structures with a per-software-timer offset to a global clock/timer. When examining if a timer will expire, the kernel simply maintains a list or tree of those elapsing next, with respect to its internal global clock/timer.